# Users who don't have enough rep to comment

Tags: discussion, comments, review-page, reputation, new-users

Now that I'm able to work a couple of the review queues I've realized how frequently people post comments as answers because they don't have enough rep to comment everywhere. How exactly are we supposed to handle those? I realize this is an effective anti-spam strategy, but that unfortunately does leave some people in the dust who are trying to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a comment stating that "This is not an answer bla bla bla..", preferable with a link to appropriate Help section (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). Also flag it for moderator attention and we will take it from there.

Comment: Does that not run the risk of making them feel unwelcome? Sorry if this discussion has happened a hundred times already, I'm just the FNG...  >.<

Comment: That is probably most dependent on the tone and wording you use in you comment :) by starting with "Hi and welcome to SP.SE :)" I think you are up to a good start. But if you feel unsure, just skip the post review in question or just flag it for moderators attention :)

Comment: Works for me, thanks!